# Excel: Use array to sum product by row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a way to use `SUMPRODUCT` or use an array formula with arrays of differing sizes?

Currently I have a list of ~1500 products in column `A`
and columns `B`-`I` contain their respective component needs like so:

```
 A        B      C      D      E      F      G      H      I      J
        ¢20   ¢55     ¢75    ¢61    ¢12    ¢30    ¢46    ¢83     total
wdgt     9      1      1      0      0      0      0      0        235
fzzy     0      0      10     9      3      1      1      0       1411
sqr      10     10     10     10     10     10     10     10      3820
llc      2      4      6      8      10     12     14     16      3650
dbl      2      4      8      16     32     64     128    256    31276
....
```

Each of the respective components has a set value , and `J` is currently calculated by

```
SUMPRODUCT(B2:I2,$B1:$I1)...
```

I would like to have `J` be an array formula like

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(B2:I6,$B1:$I1)}
```

but doing so gives #VALUE! error and:

```
{=SUM(B2:I6,$B1:$I1)}
```

for each row i.e. the sum of the total column, 40392.

Is there a way to do this with an array formula?

Comment: Please define "strange results" and "strange behavior". We don't know what that is.

Comment: Also, your formula is multiplying by the text (prt1, prt2, prt3, etc.) in the first row. That won't work. Was that your intent?

Comment: For that matter, please define "correct behavior"; i.e., what do you want it to do? Giving some examples of the results you want/expect would help us to help you get them. Also, why are you making the columns `B` and `I` absolute, but not the row numbers? And, just for good measure, what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Why would you want to SUM if you want an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via *trial and error*…

```
{=SUM(B2:I6,$B1:$I1)}
```

returns an error #VALUE!

```
{=SUM(B2:I6,$B1:$I1)}
```

returns the sum of the totals

```
{=$B$1:$I$1*B2:I6}
```

returns 180, 0, 200, 40, 40 (which I cannot explain). This was what I thought was strange.

```
{=$B$1*B2:B6+$C$1*C2:C6+…+$H$1*H2:H6+$I$1*I2:I6}
```

returns the correct totals for each row.

Alternatively, I previously had something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$1:$I$1,B2:I2)
```

in each row, but for 1500+ rows, the evaluation was getting longer and longer as the list is constantly changing and increasing.